# How to overwrite with Fprintf() in golang

Tags: html, go

My problem is: i want to print html code using golang like this:

```golang
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/",procesarRaiz)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000",nil)
}

func procesarRaiz2(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(res,"<h1>Text one</h1>")
    //then i want to remove text "text one" and put this:
    fmt.Fprintf(res,"<h1>Text 2</h1>")
}
```

When i open the browser and connect to the server, i can see two texts, but i want to replace text 1 with text 2.I have been looking for solutions but i couldnt, would be very thankful if someone can help me.

Comment: Once you have written to `res` that data is sent to the client. You cannot "take it back". You can include javascript in the HTML which will change the text, or use an `if`-statement to decide which text to send beforehand.

Comment: Oh i see :(. The real problem is that i have to print a html code in browser, wich has scripts too. I have to receive values from a server and put that values in the html code.

Comment: To achieve  that, you still need to put some js on your html. The simplest way is writing the "setInterval" javascript function to check if there is a new value in your server then update the text on your html.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "replace" it, but maybe you can trick it by using `if` statement:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", procesarRaiz)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}

func procesarRaiz(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    var str string
    condition := true

    if !condition {
        str = "<h1>Text one</h1>"
    } else {
        str = "<h1>Text 2</h1>"
    }

    // the text will be printed depending on which condition is fulfilled
    fmt.Fprintf(res, str)
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much. But i need to print a html code that contains a table, then i have to replace table values (values come from a server). That is why i was loking for a function that let me over write new values

Comment: I think it's better to use DBMS instead. You can manipulate and manage the data in your database.